# row wise operation distance R

Tags: r, row, apply, purrr

I saw this question and It is very interesting. I copy code of it.

```
library(philentropy)
normalize <- function(x) {
 return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}

knn <- function(train, test, k, method){
  n.test <- nrow(test)
  n.train <- nrow(train)
  if (n.train + n.test <= k) stop("k can not be more than n-1")
  neigh <- matrix(0, nrow = n.test, ncol = k) 
  ddist <- NULL
  for(i in 1:n.test) {
    for(j in 1:n.train) {
      xmat <- rbind(test[i,], train[j,]) 
      ddist[j] <- distance(as.data.frame(xmat), method, k)  #
    }
    neigh[i, ] <- sort(ddist)[2:(k + 1)] 
  }
  return(neigh)
}

wbcd <- read.csv("https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9781784393908/raw/ac9fe41596dd42fc3877cfa8ed410dd346c43548/Machine%20Learning%20with%20R,%20Second%20Edition_Code/Chapter%2003/wisc_bc_data.csv")
rownames(wbcd) <- wbcd$id
wbcd$id <- NULL
wbcd_n <- as.data.frame(lapply(wbcd[2:31], normalize))

wbcd_train<-wbcd_n[1:469,]
wbcd_test<-wbcd_n[470:549,]
wbcd_nn <-knn(wbcd_train, wbcd_test ,3, method="euclidean")
```

The problem is this part is slow and I want to optimize it.

```
    for(i in 1:n.test) {
        for(j in 1:n.train) {
          xmat <- rbind(test[i,], train[j,]) 
          ddist[j] <- distance(as.data.frame(xmat), method, k)  #
        }
        neigh[i, ] <- sort(ddist)[2:(k + 1)] 
      }

  return(neigh)
}
```

is there one way to use apply function or map to it?

I was trying to run something efficient but I didn't find something. Only this:

```
    f1 <- Vectorize(function(i, j) test_fun(mat1[j, ], mat2[i, ]))
out <- outer(seq_len(nrow(mat1)), seq_len(nrow(mat)), FUN = f1)
out


test_fun <- function(x, y){
  distance <- abs(x-y)
  distance <- sum(distance)
  return(distance)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Yes! There is a way to use apply or map. There is also a way to optimize this kind of loop.

Here are three ways of doing row-wise calculations on two datasets:

1. Nested `for` loops
2. Nested `map` and pipe (`%>%`)
3. C++

## 1. For loops

```
for_loops <- function(){

  tmp <- matrix( data = 0, nrow = nrow( set1 ), ncol = nrow( set2 ) )

  # Calculate the Euclidean distance as
  #  the [square root of the] sum of the squared differences
  #   between corresponding elements of two vectors
  euclidean <- function( u, v ){ sum( ( set1[ u, ] - set2[ v, ] )^2 ) }

  for( i in 1:nrow( set1 )){               # for each row in set1
    for( j in 1:nrow( set2 )){             #   and each row in set2
      tmp[ i, j ] <- euclidean( i, j )     #     process each pair of rows
    }
  }
  sqrt( tmp )
}

result_for_loops <- for_loops()
```

## 2. Map and pipe

```
require( purrr )
map_and_pipe <- function(){

  euclidean <- function( v, u ){ sum( ( set1[ u, ] - set2[ v, ] )^2 ) }

  seq( nrow( set1 )) %>%                   # for(i in 1:nrow( set1 ))
    map( function( THIS_ROW_FROM_SET1 ){   #   do this stuff for each j
      map2(
          .x = seq( nrow( set2 ))          #   for(j in 1:nrow( set2 ))
        , .y = THIS_ROW_FROM_SET1          #   and using the row from the outer loop,
        , .f = euclidean                   #     do this_stuff for each pair of rows
      )
    }) %>%
      unlist %>%
        matrix( nrow = nrow( set1 ), ncol = nrow( set2 ), byrow = TRUE ) %>%
          sqrt
}

result_map_and_pipe <- map_and_pipe()
```

## 3. C++

```
src <-
"#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double euclidean( NumericMatrix M ){

  double sum_of_squared_differences=0;
  
  for( int COLUMN_INDEX = 0; COLUMN_INDEX < M.ncol(); COLUMN_INDEX++ ){
    sum_of_squared_differences += pow( M( 0, COLUMN_INDEX ) - M( 1, COLUMN_INDEX ), 2 );
  }

  return ( sqrt( sum_of_squared_differences ) );

}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix distance_between_vectors( NumericMatrix M1, NumericMatrix M2 ){

  int ROWS_IN_TABLE1 = M1.nrow();
  int ROWS_IN_TABLE2 = M2.nrow();

  NumericMatrix scratchpad( 2, M1.ncol() );        // 1 row from each table
  NumericMatrix result( ROWS_IN_TABLE1, ROWS_IN_TABLE2 );
  
  for( int i = 0; i < ROWS_IN_TABLE1; i++  ){
    for( int j = 0; j < ROWS_IN_TABLE2; j++ ){

      scratchpad( 0, _ ) = M1( i, _ );             // row i from first table
      scratchpad( 1, _ ) = M2( j, _ );             // row j from second table
      result( i, j ) = euclidean( scratchpad );    // distance between pair of rows

    }
  }
  
  return( result );

}
"

Rcpp::sourceCpp( code = src )

C_plus_plus <- function(){
  distance_between_vectors( as.matrix( set1 ), as.matrix( set2 ) )
}
result_C_plus_plus <- C_plus_plus()
```

## Benchmarks

```
all.equal( result_for_loops, result_map_and_pipe, result_C_plus_plus )
# [1] TRUE

benchmarks <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    for_loops()
  , map_and_pipe()
  , C_plus_plus()
  , unit = "s"
  , times = 10
) -> benchmarks

print( benchmarks )
# Unit: seconds
#            expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#     for_loops() 176.23367 176.34736 177.53933 176.78680 177.97147 182.46025    10
#  map_and_pipe() 178.74360 179.96482 181.00409 180.47007 182.15763 184.14615    10
#   C_plus_plus()   0.02817   0.02838   0.02872   0.02848   0.02873   0.03092    10
```

## Conclusion

Nested for-loops and nested maps are both quite slow, compared to C++.